# how to edit sites by using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am going for build one apps script for my company Google Site ,Please let me know how to edit the Site 
by using Google Apps Script.

Comment: How about spending some time with the [Google App Script tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles)

Comment: Please tell me any one tutorial which will help me for editing Google site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97520?hl=en) for the tutorial if you want to change your site's layout, Theme, colors or font.

However if you want to edit your Google Site by using Google Apps Script, here are the links that will be useful:

1. https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1224164
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks , Please let me know if i want to search a particular content in site and want to rename that content . Please help on this .